# Blade View Cache Not Being Updated (Envoyer)

Tags: laravel, envoyer.io

Blade view is not updating cache in my latest deployment, instead when I deploy a latest code, Blade view caches from the previous deployment (or maybe from somewhere else, this is my guess). My blade view is updated with latest release. Even when I manually clear the cache (from `storage/framework/views`) and do `php artisan view:clear` `php artisan cache:clear`, the changes still does not cache from the latest deployment.

Comment: Did you try to delete the files in storage/framework/views? Did you try php artisan cache:clear ?

Comment: Try Ctrl + F5 to clear cache

Comment: @Komal Thank You so much for your valuable solution.

Comment: @MukeshDhama You welcome :)  Your problem is solved or not??

Comment: @MukeshDhama sorry for not read  your question carefully. Did you read my answer carefully? There are two other answers with my second solution cleaning cache. But maybe you did not read it and focus on call me out for for not reading your question carefully.

Comment: Ok . Good luck with your actitud!

Comment: @MukeshDhama How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

run the commands `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` and then reflesh (F5) the browser

Comment: This didn't happened to me on Laravel 5.8 only in Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

run this command `php artisan cache:clear` and then refresh browser with Ctrl+Shift+R

Answer (score 0):

In Envoyer, edit the server from the Servers tab and check the checkbox near `Reload FPM After Deployments`

save and deploy